# How to split R dataframe into list based on character variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have election data that looks mostly like this:

```
  t1        t2          t3          t4         
  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
1 CONTEST 1 NA          NA          NA         
2 Precinct  Candidate 1 Candidate 2 Candidate 3
3 PE01      1           4           2          
4 PE02      5           3           2          
5 CONTEST 2 NA          NA          NA         
6 Precinct  Candidate 1 Candidate 2 Candidate 3
7 PE01      2           1           5          
8 PE02      4           2           3
```

In order the pivot the data, I’ve created a new variable contest where I move over the contest name and `fill` down, `group_by` contest, and `group_split`. Then `map_dfr` a function to get rid of the first row, move the 2nd (now 1st) row to variable names (super easy with `janitor`'s `row_to_names`), and `pivot_longer`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(janitor)
library(purrr)

t_lst <- t %>% 
  mutate(contest = if_else(str_detect(t1, " "), t1, NA_character_), .before = t1) %>% 
  fill(contest, .direction = "down") %>% 
  group_by(contest) %>% 
  group_split()

e_pivot <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    slice(-1) %>% 
    row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = 3:last_col(), names_to = "candidate", values_to = "votes") %>% 
    rename(contest = 1, precinct = Precinct) %>%
    mutate(votes = as.numeric(votes))
}

map_dfr(t_lst, e_pivot)
```

Works great, I get this and can now actually use the data.

```
 contest   precinct candidate   votes
   <chr>     <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>
 1 CONTEST 1 PE01     Candidate 1     1
 2 CONTEST 1 PE01     Candidate 2     4
 3 CONTEST 1 PE01     Candidate 3     2
 4 CONTEST 1 PE02     Candidate 1     5
 5 CONTEST 1 PE02     Candidate 2     3
 6 CONTEST 1 PE02     Candidate 3     2
 7 CONTEST 2 PE01     Candidate 1     2
 8 CONTEST 2 PE01     Candidate 2     1
 9 CONTEST 2 PE01     Candidate 3     5
10 CONTEST 2 PE02     Candidate 1     4
11 CONTEST 2 PE02     Candidate 2     2
12 CONTEST 2 PE02     Candidate 3     3
```

BUT I’ve realized for some of the contests, there are so many candidates that the contests repeat, so the data looks like this:

```
 t1        t2          t3          t4         
  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
1 CONTEST 1 NA          NA          NA         
2 Precinct  Candidate 1 Candidate 2 Candidate 3
3 PE01      1           4           2          
4 PE02      5           3           2          
5 CONTEST 1 NA          NA          NA         
6 Precinct  Candidate 4 Candidate 5 Candidate 6
7 PE01      2           1           5          
8 PE02      4           2           3
```

At which point my group-split-pivot-combine approach doesn’t work.

I don’t need the data to be split by contest per se, just by where the candidate names are so I can pivot correctly. So long as I have each candidate identified with the right contest in the final output all is good. I ended up using the `group_by` contest because I needed the contest as a variable regardless and it was a straightforward approach.

I’m struggling to figure out a different way to identify where to split the data. My thought is to use the same `str_detect` a space to identify where to split, but my searches online have not led me to figure out how exactly to do that. Many questions on this site seeming to ask how to split by value get answers that aren't applicable here (often because they didn't need to split, or the answer uses `group_split`). I also found some great answers for pandas data.frames in python which similarly, do not apply here.

dput of sample of the actual data (the decimals are there because the election uses cumulative voting):

```
structure(list(V1 = c("FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE", "Precinct", 
"PE01", "PE02", "PE03", "PE04", "PE05", "PE06", "PE07", "PE08", 
"PE09", "PE10", "PE11", "PE12", "PE13", "PE14", "PE15", "PE16", 
"PE17", "PE18", "PE19", "PE20", "PE21", "PE22", "PE23", "PE24", 
"PE25", "PE26", "PE27", "PE28", "PE29", "PE30", "PE31", "PE32", 
"PE33", "PE34", "PE35", "PE36", "PE37", "PE38", "PE39", "PE40", 
"PE41", "PE42", "PE43", "PE44", "PE45", "PE46", "PE47", "PE48", 
"PE49", "PE50", "FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE", "Precinct", "PE01", 
"PE02", "PE03", "PE04", "PE05", "PE06", "PE07", "PE08", "PE09", 
"PE10", "PE11", "PE12", "PE13", "PE14", "PE15", "PE16", "PE17", 
"PE18", "PE19", "PE20", "PE21", "PE22", "PE23", "PE24", "PE25", 
"PE26", "PE27", "PE28", "PE29", "PE30", "PE31", "PE32", "PE33", 
"PE34", "PE35", "PE36", "PE37", "PE38", "PE39", "PE40", "PE41", 
"PE42", "PE43", "PE44", "PE45", "PE46", "PE47", "PE48", "PE49", 
"PE50"), V8 = c(NA, "Beth Jensen", "4.5000", "2.0000", "4.0000", 
"18.2500", "1.0000", "21.1667", "30.2500", "10.5833", "8.7500", 
"11.8333", "10.5000", "48.6667", "14.2500", "18.1667", "81.8333", 
"35.3333", "52.0833", "143.1667", "155.1667", "136.7500", "17.5000", 
"14.2500", "12.1667", "4.9167", "24.6667", "34.8333", "108.6667", 
"44.5000", "80.5000", "64.6667", "18.7500", "4.0000", "36.4167", 
"44.5000", "12.6667", "36.5000", "19.9167", "74.4167", "19.8333", 
"47.0000", "25.4167", "26.2500", "58.0000", "49.0833", "79.6667", 
"47.2500", "36.3333", "129.2500", "61.4167", "65.9167", NA, "John L. Kelly", 
"6.2500", "0.0000", "2.0000", "2.5000", "1.0000", "6.0000", "36.9167", 
"3.3333", "0.0000", "5.0000", "0.0000", "18.6667", "7.6667", 
"2.0000", "21.2500", "4.1667", "3.0000", "8.1667", "26.0000", 
"26.5000", "0.0000", "7.5000", "16.5833", "2.6667", "3.6667", 
"22.3333", "64.0000", "10.0000", "29.8333", "48.8333", "6.5000", 
"14.6667", "5.5000", "6.7500", "0.0000", "20.7500", "1.0000", 
"85.5833", "8.0000", "34.7500", "10.1667", "7.3333", "31.2500", 
"29.2500", "57.0833", "60.3333", "30.5000", "66.5000", "31.9167", 
"39.2500"), V9 = c(NA, "Zachary M. Oyler", "1.6667", "1.0000", 
"7.1667", "10.5000", "7.0000", "1.0000", "13.5833", "5.8333", 
"7.0000", "4.6667", "25.0000", "39.0833", "4.7500", "11.6667", 
"35.2500", "9.6667", "8.1667", "23.0833", "20.0000", "32.8333", 
"3.9167", "42.4167", "33.5000", "3.6667", "40.1667", "50.8333", 
"79.1667", "58.6667", "123.0833", "137.2500", "24.3333", "5.5000", 
"13.3333", "6.6667", "6.0000", "6.4167", "5.9167", "48.5000", 
"19.5000", "15.5000", "24.6667", "26.3333", "60.1667", "34.5833", 
"46.5000", "27.3333", "57.5000", "104.0000", "40.5000", "95.3333", 
NA, "Beth Akeson", "10.0000", "1.0000", "1.0000", "5.5000", "1.0000", 
"2.2500", "9.0000", "3.7500", "1.0000", "1.0000", "1.6667", "16.3333", 
"18.0000", "4.5000", "25.9167", "6.0000", "14.0000", "16.2500", 
"19.6667", "23.0833", "2.0000", "2.0000", "3.6667", "3.6667", 
"12.6667", "11.0000", "72.0833", "10.8333", "46.2500", "12.5000", 
"6.9167", "3.5000", "8.8333", "15.6667", "3.9167", "5.0000", 
"5.7500", "82.0000", "10.0000", "16.7500", "17.4167", "19.6667", 
"33.7500", "33.5833", "41.2500", "18.1667", "29.3333", "63.2500", 
"30.3333", "20.6667"), V10 = c(NA, "Rita Ali", "79.9167", "100.5000", 
"65.7500", "183.5000", "63.5000", "80.0833", "166.5000", "128.2500", 
"253.5833", "222.7500", "292.7500", "125.5833", "68.6667", "68.0000", 
"93.9167", "98.4167", "71.0000", "41.2500", "24.8333", "91.7500", 
"92.9167", "141.1667", "118.4167", "125.5000", "108.3333", "100.6667", 
"93.2500", "102.5833", "88.6667", "96.8333", "94.6667", "63.3333", 
"102.9167", "86.0833", "80.7500", "87.0833", "39.3333", "73.1667", 
"29.3333", "117.5833", "108.5833", "89.6667", "175.9167", "90.8333", 
"81.1667", "100.0000", "58.7500", "96.7500", "88.5000", "105.5000", 
NA, "Aaron T. Chess Jr.", "4.5000", "11.0000", "10.6667", "8.5000", 
"35.0000", "19.3333", "28.0000", "6.4167", "20.8333", "12.2500", 
"21.4167", "5.3333", "11.1667", "2.0000", "1.0000", "8.6667", 
"0.0000", "2.5000", "2.0000", "2.2500", "11.6667", "3.5000", 
"9.2500", "10.3333", "17.5000", "11.1667", "5.5000", "3.9167", 
"1.0000", "2.2500", "5.0000", "5.1667", "9.3333", "1.0000", "12.0000", 
"12.6667", "7.6667", "0.0000", "3.0000", "11.0000", "11.1667", 
"16.5000", "1.0000", "8.9167", "7.3333", "1.0000", "2.0000", 
"5.0000", "5.7500", "7.9167"), V11 = c(NA, "Sid Ruckriegel", 
"1.6667", "3.0000", "3.0000", "7.0000", "6.0000", "2.6667", "40.2500", 
"7.6667", "7.0000", "3.6667", "10.0000", "46.7500", "7.6667", 
"25.6667", "30.2500", "34.5833", "20.0000", "79.0000", "42.0000", 
"62.0833", "6.2500", "7.4167", "28.9167", "4.3333", "27.0000", 
"21.0000", "81.1667", "26.0000", "53.8333", "56.5000", "12.3333", 
"6.5000", "31.8333", "20.6667", "3.5000", "11.0833", "18.2500", 
"98.8333", "19.1667", "34.7500", "20.6667", "20.3333", "41.5000", 
"43.9167", "64.8333", "57.5833", "45.8333", "120.1667", "35.0000", 
"44.9167", NA, "Kevin R. Sibley", "5.0000", "0.0000", "0.0000", 
"0.0000", "2.0000", "2.0000", "1.0000", "0.0000", "1.0000", "2.0000", 
"1.0000", "2.0000", "2.0000", "7.0000", "6.0000", "5.0000", "1.0000", 
"0.0000", "0.0000", "20.0000", "0.0000", "10.0000", "0.0000", 
"6.2500", "7.0000", "3.0000", "6.4167", "6.6667", "3.5000", "16.0000", 
"0.0000", "10.0000", "6.0000", "4.5000", "1.0000", "3.2500", 
"2.6667", "21.0000", "3.6667", "27.2500", "0.0000", "10.0000", 
"2.6667", "2.0000", "2.0000", "4.7500", "12.6667", "7.0000", 
"59.7500", "7.1667"), V12 = c(NA, "Peter Kobak", "4.7500", "1.0000", 
"3.9167", "3.5000", "1.0000", "10.5833", "40.7500", "2.6667", 
"3.7500", "11.9167", "27.0000", "31.8333", "5.9167", "23.5000", 
"76.4167", "76.0000", "74.1667", "51.0833", "104.6667", "163.7500", 
"17.8333", "0.0000", "21.5833", "16.1667", "20.7500", "44.6667", 
"64.9167", "54.2500", "52.4167", "32.5833", "23.9167", "14.5000", 
"42.4167", "19.5833", "6.2500", "20.9167", "12.0000", "50.2500", 
"26.3333", "60.1667", "9.5833", "20.8333", "44.1667", "36.4167", 
"26.6667", "12.7500", "32.4167", "61.3333", "50.5000", "55.8333", 
NA, "James B. Golden", "2.5000", "0.0000", "3.5000", "0.0000", 
"5.0000", "1.0000", "10.0000", "1.0000", "2.0000", "1.0000", 
"0.0000", "5.3333", "0.0000", "0.0000", "4.1667", "1.6667", "7.1667", 
"0.0000", "0.0000", "6.6667", "0.0000", "6.0000", "0.0000", "0.0000", 
"1.2500", "2.0000", "6.1667", "2.0000", "1.0000", "3.0000", "1.0000", 
"1.0000", "5.5000", "2.0000", "2.0000", "2.0000", "0.0000", "2.0000", 
"1.0000", "2.0000", "0.0000", "1.0000", "1.0000", "0.0000", "7.2500", 
"9.0000", "3.2500", "0.0000", "3.0000", "6.6667"), V13 = c(NA, 
"Branden Martin", "10.0000", "0.0000", "1.0000", "9.5000", "0.0000", 
"7.0000", "4.9167", "1.6667", "0.0000", "1.0000", "3.0000", "34.8333", 
"6.7500", "6.0000", "15.9167", "16.5000", "7.8333", "7.2500", 
"7.0000", "5.0000", "0.0000", "1.0000", "4.7500", "0.0000", "3.6667", 
"9.1667", "35.9167", "14.3333", "32.8333", "27.7500", "10.3333", 
"5.5000", "5.0000", "9.0000", "1.0000", "11.7500", "5.3333", 
"18.8333", "9.6667", "18.1667", "27.8333", "20.2500", "39.5833", 
"15.3333", "48.1667", "26.5000", "37.2500", "41.0000", "50.1667", 
"10.9167", NA, "Mary Nell Hayes", "1.2500", "0.0000", "6.0000", 
"2.2500", "2.0000", "2.2500", "13.6667", "0.0000", "8.0000", 
"6.0000", "1.6667", "5.1667", "2.5000", "0.0000", "5.0000", "2.0000", 
"2.6667", "5.2500", "1.0000", "0.0000", "0.0000", "0.0000", "2.0000", 
"0.0000", "2.0000", "0.0000", "11.6667", "1.0000", "1.0000", 
"5.1667", "2.0000", "2.0000", "5.6667", "8.6667", "1.0000", "8.8333", 
"1.0000", "1.0000", "2.0000", "5.6667", "1.2500", "0.0000", "1.0000", 
"1.0000", "4.5000", "5.1667", "2.0000", "2.9167", "2.0000", "6.0000"
), V14 = c(NA, "Janice Louise Lindsay", "1.0000", "7.0000", "16.4167", 
"13.7500", "2.0000", "16.4167", "5.0000", "5.8333", "3.0000", 
"13.1667", "11.4167", "9.0000", "13.6667", "7.0000", "9.5000", 
"5.2500", "4.2500", "0.0000", "0.0000", "1.0000", "5.5000", "6.6667", 
"3.2500", "4.3333", "12.1667", "2.0000", "4.2500", "8.6667", 
"2.0000", "9.7500", "16.5833", "1.0000", "7.1667", "7.6667", 
"0.0000", "3.6667", "4.5000", "2.2500", "2.0000", "3.0000", "6.6667", 
"2.0000", "8.0000", "2.5000", "1.2500", "9.0000", "4.5000", "5.9167", 
"4.5000", "9.3333", NA, "Andre W. Allen", "17.0000", "18.5000", 
"27.5833", "8.0000", "8.5000", "17.2500", "43.1667", "17.0000", 
"14.0833", "27.7500", "38.5833", "20.4167", "31.0000", "8.5000", 
"26.5833", "14.7500", "16.1667", "7.0000", "16.6667", "38.5833", 
"26.4167", "28.0833", "39.9167", "52.1667", "52.5000", "51.3333", 
"28.6667", "29.5833", "52.4167", "48.9167", "12.6667", "10.3333", 
"28.0833", "35.2500", "36.4167", "25.0833", "5.0000", "33.0000", 
"21.5000", "33.4167", "61.5833", "23.8333", "70.7500", "17.5833", 
"23.3333", "33.1667", "20.1667", "35.2500", "36.1667", "42.0833"
)), row.names = c(NA, -104L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is.na()` on the second column to detect where the new blocks starts.  Then `cumsum(is.na())` will give you an id for each block.  Group on this, not the contest name.

```
e_pivot <- function(x) {
    x %>% 
        select(-block_id) %>%
        slice(-1) %>% 
        row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>% 
        pivot_longer(cols = 3:last_col(), names_to = "candidate", values_to = "votes") %>% 
        rename(contest = 1, precinct = Precinct) %>%
        mutate(votes = as.numeric(votes))
}

t %>% 
    mutate(contest = if_else(str_detect(V1, " "), V1, NA_character_),,
           block_id = cumsum(is.na(V8)),
           .before = V1) %>% 
    fill(contest, .direction = "down") %>% 
    group_by(block_id) %>% 
    group_split() %>% 
    map_dfr(e_pivot)
```

Comment: Simple solution, easy to understand. `cumsum` is a function I've seen used often and I've known abstractly is useful but haven't ever quite figured out how to make use of myself. This makes total sense, thank you.

Comment: I use `cumsum` like this very often to identify groups of consecutive rows.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rename_with(~str_c('t', seq_along(.))) %>%
  mutate(CONTEST = ifelse(if_all(-1,is.na), t1, NA), 
         Precinct = ifelse(is.na(CONTEST),t1, NA),
         t1 = NULL, .before=1) %>%
  fill(CONTEST) %>%
  filter(!if_all(-1,is.na))%>%
  pivot_longer(-(1:2)) %>%
  mutate(grouper = str_detect(value, "^\\D")) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(1, diff(grouper)) ==1)) %>%
  mutate(name = setNames(value[grouper], name[grouper])[name]) %>%
  filter(!grouper) %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value), grouper = NULL)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   grp [2]
   CONTEST   Precinct name        value   grp
   <chr>     <chr>    <chr>       <dbl> <int>
 1 CONTEST 1 PE01     Candidate 1     1     1
 2 CONTEST 1 PE01     Candidate 2     4     1
 3 CONTEST 1 PE01     Candidate 3     2     1
 4 CONTEST 1 PE02     Candidate 1     5     1
 5 CONTEST 1 PE02     Candidate 2     3     1
 6 CONTEST 1 PE02     Candidate 3     2     1
 7 CONTEST 1 PE01     Candidate 4     2     2
 8 CONTEST 1 PE01     Candidate 5     1     2
 9 CONTEST 1 PE01     Candidate 6     5     2
10 CONTEST 1 PE02     Candidate 4     4     2
11 CONTEST 1 PE02     Candidate 5     2     2
12 CONTEST 1 PE02     Candidate 6     3     2
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# set to  data.table format
setDT(mydata)
# split to list on the for FOR in the first column
L <- split(mydata, f = cumsum(grepl("^FOR", mydata$V1)))
# set names of the list
names(L) <- sapply(L, function(x) x[1,1], simplify = TRUE)
# drop the first row,
#  set the second row as colnames
#  and melt to long format
L <- lapply(L, function(x) {
  setnames(x, as.character(test[2,]))
  melt(x[-(1:2), ], id.vars = "Precinct")
})
# rowbind together, use names of L as id
DT <- rbindlist(L, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE, id = "event")
# result
                       event Precinct              variable   value
1: FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE     PE01           Beth Jensen  4.5000
2: FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE     PE02           Beth Jensen  2.0000
3: FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE     PE03           Beth Jensen  4.0000
4: FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE     PE04           Beth Jensen 18.2500
5: FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE     PE05           Beth Jensen  1.0000
---                                                                 
696: FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE     PE46 Janice Louise Lindsay 33.1667
697: FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE     PE47 Janice Louise Lindsay 20.1667
698: FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE     PE48 Janice Louise Lindsay 35.2500
699: FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE     PE49 Janice Louise Lindsay 36.1667
700: FOR CITY COUNCIL AT LARGE     PE50 Janice Louise Lindsay 42.0833
                         event Precinct              variable   value
```